# Windows - SDL_PumpEvents resets to system cursor

Tags: c++, windows, cursor, mouse, sdl

I'm using engine which uses SDL 1.2.5. I can't change SDL version or not use this engine. I need custom mouse cursor. I loaded cur file properly and used the `SetCursor` method but every time I call `SDL_PumpEvents` my custom cursor is replaced by SDL's default black one. I could turn off system cursor and draw it manually but that way cursor is delayed and it's noticeable. I'm programming a game so any cursor delays are unwelcome. Is there any way to tell SDL to not changing cursor? Or to lock the `SetCursor` method?

Answer (score 0):

You could place the `SetCursor` function in your gameloop so it sets the cursor after the events get handled